# Reading unicode chars from text file in C

Tags: c, unicode

I am trying to read pascal code from .pas file and write it in console line by line. That part is working fine. Now I want to add Turkish characters in .pas file that I'm reading from and display it.
I've included

```
#include <locale.h>
```

and `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");`

When I write Şperator which contains Turkish character instead of Operator program prints out Å?perator. I want it to print out Şperator. What is problem?

[image: Pascal code]

Here is full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wchar.h>



#define FORM_FEED_CHAR    '\f'

#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH    32
#define MAX_SOURCE_LINE_LENGTH  256
#define MAX_PRINT_LINE_LENGTH   120
#define MAX_LINES_PER_PAGE      50
#define DATE_STRING_LENGTH      26

typedef enum {
    FALSE, TRUE,
}BOOLEAN;

int line_number = 0;
int page_number = 0;
int level = 0;
int line_count = MAX_LINES_PER_PAGE;

char source_buffer[MAX_SOURCE_LINE_LENGTH];

char source_name[MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
char date[DATE_STRING_LENGTH];

FILE*source_file;

main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
    BOOLEAN get_source_line();

    init_lister("C:/Users/Dzenan/Documents/calculator1.pas");
    while (get_source_line());
}

init_lister(name)
char *name;
{
    time_t timer;
    strcpy(source_name, name);
    source_file = fopen(source_name, "r");

    time(&timer);
    strcpy(date, "d");
}

BOOLEAN
get_source_line()
{
    char print_buffer[MAX_SOURCE_LINE_LENGTH + 9];
    if ((fgets(source_buffer, MAX_SOURCE_LINE_LENGTH,
            source_file)) != NULL) {
        ++line_number;
        sprintf(print_buffer, "%4d %d: %s",
            line_number, level, source_buffer);
        print_line(print_buffer);
        return(TRUE);
    }
    else return(FALSE);
}

print_line(line)
char line[];
{
    char save_ch;
    char *save_chp = NULL;

    if (++line_count > MAX_LINES_PER_PAGE) {
        print_page_header();
        line_count = 1;
    };

    if (strlen(line)> MAX_PRINT_LINE_LENGTH)
    save_chp = &line[MAX_PRINT_LINE_LENGTH];

    if(save_chp){
        save_ch = *save_chp;
        *save_chp = '\0';
    }

    printf("%s", line);

    if(save_chp) *save_chp = save_ch;

}

print_page_header() {
    putchar(FORM_FEED_CHAR);
    printf("Page %d  %s  %s\n\n", ++page_number, source_name, date);
}
```

Comment: `save_chp = &line[MAX_PRINT_LINE_LENGTH];` off-by-one

Comment: Your problem is likly one of encoding. I guess that your source text is encoded in UTF-8. The character Ş is U+015e, which encodes to the UTF-8 sequence c5 9e. The encoding of the console is probably Latin1, where the A with a ring is c5 and 93 isn't a legal Unicode character and therefore repesented as question mark. Try redirecting the output to a file, then view the file as UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Picture has poor readable - post text as text.

Comment: @MOehm, I don't think console is the problem because I can run this code
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish"); 
printf("fistikçi sahap");

in other file and it prints it out right. I guess problem is somewhere in the file reading.

Comment: By "source code" I meant the Pascal source code hat you read in. The problem is the mismatch of encoding between that file and the console. At least that's what I assume.

Comment: @chux that's just your screen. Or sight. Everything is OK.

Comment: Post the code in that image as text.

Comment: Don't post screen shots of code or error messages. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: once you use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");` you'll work in ANSI, not Unicode. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

That's not your problem - you just need to configure terminal emulator (cmd.exe) encoding properly. C strings do not have encoding. They're just sequences of bytes. Your program prints exactly what's in the file which is probably encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: If that is the case why when I print this printf("fistikçi sahap") it prints message which contains unicode characters exactly like it is?
I have also changed cmd encoding but result is still the same.

Comment: Because your `print` statement uses your current code page when you type it, it round-trips perfectly, and you don't need to know which enooding it uses for the string under the hood. Not so when you are dealing with text in a different encoding. The simple solution in the long run is [UTF-8 everywhere.](http://utf8everywhere.com/)

Comment: Strings are sequences of bytes. In files too. Your text editor basically writes bytes instead of characters. Your program treats them as separate bytes too. But your terminal treats them as unicode characters and tries to display them in such way.

Comment: You do not even need to set locale - it does not really define the encoding. It defines stuff like date format, currency etc.

Answer (score 0):

`setlocale` will only change the ANSI code page. It's not the same thing as Unicode. Your code will work if the file is saved in Turkish code page. Check the file code page to make sure.

To print Unicode in Windows console, use UTF-16. Example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
...
HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
const wchar_t *wstr = L"Şperator\n";
DWORD temp;
WriteConsoleW(h, wstr, wcslen(wstr), &temp, 0);
```

Use the following code if the source file is in UTF-8. Note that the file is opened in binary mode. If source file is Turkish code page, then use `CP_ACP` or Turkish code page instead of `CP_UTF8`. In the unlikely case that code page is UTF-16, skip the `MultiByteToWideChar` conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD temp;

    FILE *fp = fopen("utf8.txt", "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t filesize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *buf = malloc(filesize + 1);
    fread(buf, 1, filesize, fp);
    buf[filesize] = 0;

    int widesize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, -1, 0, 0);
    wchar_t *wbuf = malloc(widesize * 2);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, -1, wbuf, widesize);
    WriteConsoleW(h, wbuf, widesize, &temp, 0);

    free(buf);
    free(wbuf);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```